# Assigning display property to variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm trying to optimize and shorten my functions and I use `obj.style.display = 'block';` quite a few times. Am I able to assign that to a variable I can reuse?

Consider this example

```
document.getElementById('example').visible;
```

Where `.visible` is the variable for `.style.display = 'block';`.

Thanks

Comment: I think the closest you can get is extending prototype of the `Object` (or `HTMLElement`) with new method. Then use it like `document.getElementById('example').visible('none');` to set and `document.getElementById('example').visible();` to get. However this is not cool.

Comment: @dfsq In the case of visibility you could always polyfill the HTML5 `hidden` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function setDisplay (obj, display) {
   obj.style.display = display;
}

setDisplay(document.getElementById('test'), 'block');
```

You can also try something like this if you want it to look nicer:

```
function getById(id) {
   var obj = document.getElementById(id);
   obj.display = function (display) {
       this.style.display = display;
   };

   return obj;
}

var test = getById('test');
test.display('block');
```

Finally, you could use a framework that eases DOM manipulation if you're going to be doing it a lot, like jQuery.

Comment: was just about to answer the exact same thing... http://jsfiddle.net/yusafkhaliq/7mFe5/

Comment: that's what i love about javascript, the way you can extend objects on the go

Comment: `this` still confuses me :P, i always find my way out however, and yh it makes things a lot simpler when documenting you're work as these days people are running into jquery before plain ol' JavaScript so it also makes your work easier for "them" :P to use

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function

```
function set_visible(obj, visibility) {
    obj.style.display = visibility;
}
```

There is no way to store a chain of properties in a variable.

Answer (score -2):

If you're not averse to js libraries, why not use jQuery?  That way you could really simplify:-

```
$("#example").show();
```

Comment: Since the OP is looking to optimize his code, I doubt including a entire library for something this simple would be the answer.

Comment: Fair enough, was just providing the option.

Comment: this is a fair enough answer considering jquery really is still JavaScript, and come on who's not using a library, no one has time to code for multi-browser bugs/issues

Comment: @YusafKhaliq - You're misinterpreting my comment on this question. I love jQuery as much as the next guy, however the OP is looking to optimize his code and while jQuery would certainly be one way to accomplish the ultimate goal, it certainly doesn't help the OP optimize anything.

Comment: i know what you're saying i wasn't addresing you however :P it was the downvotes